# printing arrays break error

Tags: c, arrays, printing

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char name[24];

int main(void)
{
    printf("Type the name of a cartoon character.");
    printf(">>> ");
    scanf_s("%s", name);

    printf("\n\nCharacter name: %s", name);
    return 0;
}
```

I am having an issue getting this to print out.  I am not exactly sure where things are going wrong since the compiler doesn't give me any errors.  However,
I get a break error when running the program.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Reading the man-page of `scanf_s` would have helped ... Always read the documentation of functions you use! And enable all recommended warnings! A half-way modern compiler should warn.

Comment: I use scanf_s because the visual studio will not let me run the program as just scanf.  Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Yes: use it correctly! For the rest: see my 1st comment.

Comment: " Is there a way to fix this?" The documentation on `scanf_s` given examples of correct usage.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx

Comment: OK, let me show some pity: `scanf_s` wants the size of the buffer as the third argument, so `scanf_s("%23s", name,(unsigned)_countof(name) )` should do it. As described in the manpage, btw.

Comment: @deamentiaemundi: What is `_countof`? Why not use `sizeof`? That already yields the correct type (`rsize_t`, which is the same as `size_t`). Passing an `unsigned` invokes UB on systems where these types are not identical (e.g. typical 64 bit systems)

Comment: @Olaf  It is a MS-way to get the length of an array. Got it from the manpage ;-)

Comment: @deamentiaemundi: Oh, the this is another incompatibility. `scanf_s` is actually a standard C function and I got my information from the authoritative resource. Anyway, this is a `char []`, so `sizeof` is guaranteed to yield the length.

Comment: @ShawnSmith MSVC issues a warning about using `scanf`, not an error. You can defeat that warning with `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` before any `#include` statements.

Comment: @Olaf Authorative source? Oh, not MSDN? How come?

Comment: @deamentiaemundi: most likely MSDN is not the maintainer of the C standard. http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#K.3.5.3.4

Comment: @Weather Vane I actually just came across that #define statement.  It does remove the error for scanf, thanks for that.

Comment: @deamentiaemundi I understand this.  The fix this in my second comment was about the scanf error i was getting.  Now back to the issue I'm having, is that for some reason I keep getting a breakpoint hit for this code and nothing happens.  Could this be an issue with Visual Studio itself?  Maybe my computer?  I'm not quite sure as I believe this code should run.  Its completely basic code with no advanced usage of code.

Comment: There has been several direct and indirect comments to the effect that `scanf_s("%s",...);` requires *two* arguments: the address of the target, and the length constraint. RTM. And MSVC plainly warns that your second argument is missing.

Answer (score 0):

I want to thanks all those that attempted to help me.  I noticed something that didn't make sense after stepping away for a bit. Thank you for supplying this bit of code:

```
    #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
```

This made it possible to use scanf since MSVC wants scanf_s.  This is the working code.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>

char question(void);
char name[24];

char main(void)
{
    question();
    system("pause");
}

char question(void)
{
    printf("Type the name of a cartoon character >>> ");
    scanf("%s", name);

    printf("\n\"%23s\"\n\n\n", name);

    return 0;
}
```

I originally had main as an int variadic instead of char.  Not sure why MSVC didn't throw an argument at me, but it completely ignored the difference in the two.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that your scan function is wrong. If you are working in C, it should be `scanf()`.

Also for printing an array is difficult in C. You have to loop through every element in the array and print it.

So:

```
for(x ; i < n ; i++){
  printf("Element is: %s" , name[i])
}
```

Comment: `scanf_s` is part of the optional bounds-checking interface. It is nevertheless part of the standard. And OP apparently has no array of arrays, resp. array of pointers to arrays.

Comment: iterating over a char array to print a string? if at all, the placeholder would be %c, not %s. scanf_s is a microsoft addition that checks buffer boundaries.

Comment: Yes you would need %c fsor a char array for some reason I just used %s for a string array.

Comment: @JustinBesteman, Florian Heer, Olaf  Thank You.  The book I am reading for my class uses %s throughout in C.  I will change it to %c.